# why my website display in FB Login window After Login through facebook?

Tags: java, gwt, facebook

I am Integrating Face book application with Our Website.
My Website is in Java's [Google Web Toolkit] Framework 2.0.1

When we press FB-connect connect then FB's Login window comes, after that user enters 
email & pwd.

> When user clicks FB's connect button  then Our website display in that Login  window.
>   
>  Authentication and  Connect Url is Proper http://localhost:8090/websitename/
>   How to solve this problem ? 
>   Where I did mistake ? 
>   Is there any solution?

When I did same thing in GWT's development/Hosted mode with Authentication and  Connect url  http:/127.0.0.1:8888/ then works properly.
Then why It create Probelm in localhost? :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create new application, and provide My website url in Everywhere i.e

 authentication : Post-Authorize Callback URL / Post-Remove Callback URL

 Canvas : Canvas Callback URL

 Connect : Connect URL / Account Preview URL.

And my problem is solved Now :) !!!

Answer (score 0):

On some browsers, localhost is not allowed to save cookies.

Try to deploy the app to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: ...Or try a different browser that may allow localhost to store cookies.

Comment: Thanks for Reply 
Hello Friend[zz coder].
I tried it in safari,Google chrome,same thing happen.
One thing i forgot to mention that ,Initially same problem not occurs in Local host.

Hope for BEST Co-operation from your side